# Einstein field equations in the presence of an electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Here are two equivalent formulations of the Einstein field equations:

$$
R_{\mu \nu}-\frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu \nu}=8 \pi G T_{\mu \nu}
$$

$$
R_{\mu \nu}=8 \pi G\left(T_{\mu \nu}-\frac{1}{2} T g_{\mu \nu}\right).
$$

My question would be: do these change in the presence of an electromagnetic field? If so, how?

Comment: They don't change. All EM energy/momentum effects  are encoded in the source term $T_{\mu\nu}$

Comment: If the only sources are electromagnetic fields, the latter equation simplifies a bit, since $T = 0$ automatically for the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor.

Comment: Right! Related to this: if, say, we have both an EM field and some other form of energy as well (let's say, a fluid), do we add up the two energy-momentum tensors? e.g $$T_{\mu\nu}^{total} = T_{\mu\nu}^{EM} + T_{\mu\nu}^{fluid} $$ ?

Comment: "do we add up the two energy-momentum tensor?" What matters is how the energy part of the Lagrangian density (i.e. not including $\frac{\sqrt{|g|}(R-2\Lambda)}{2\kappa}$) decomposes. If it's just the some of two parts, your idea works; but if there's also an EM-fluid interaction term, that'll show up in $T_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Read some 10 pages of Dirac's 75-page brochure on GR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both valid, but the second can be simplified if only the electromagnetic field is present as a stress-energy-momentum source.

The presence of the electromagnetic field is completely encoded in $T_{ab}$. This tensor codifies all of the electromagnetic stress, energy, and momentum, which are precisely the sources of gravity. Hence, the gravitational effects induced by the EM field are already described in the equations you wrote.

However, if the electromagnetic field is *the only* contribution to $T_{ab}$ (i.e., if there are no other fields in spacetime, nor point particles, etc), then it is also true that $T = 0$ (the [electromagnetic stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) is traceless). Hence, the second equation gets simplified to
$$R_{ab} = 8\pi G T_{ab}.$$

If there are other sources of energy, this might not be true, for their stress-energy tensors might not be traceless. As mentioned in the comments, the full stress-energy tensor might then look something like
$$T_{ab} = T_{ab}^{\text{EM}} + T_{ab}^{\text{fluid}} + T_{ab}^{\text{interaction}},$$
where $T_{ab}^{\text{interaction}}$ comes from interaction terms between the electromagnetic field and the fluid, for example.

Answer (score -1):

To answer this properly would take the full theory of quantum gravity as electromagnetism is a quantum phenomena. However, such a full theory is not available. We, at present, have a few contenders and some clues like Hawking radiation.

What we can do is QFT over curved space and recall that electromagnetism is formulated as a QFT.